# Is it possible to load Hive data into Vora?

Tags: hive, hana, vora

I checked the Developer guide but didn't find the answer. So far I was able to load CSV and ORC files from HDFS to Vora, but am able to load from Hive?

In absence of specifying Hive as a source, I tried to use "paths" equal to `/apps/hive/warehouse/tablename/00000_0` (or whatever is the partial file name). However, if a Hive table is represented by multiple files in the `/tablename/` directory, I'd have to explicitly list them in "paths", which is not an ideal option. Is there any better way?

Update: The context for this question is that while Vora doesn't provide data persistence, I'd like to use Hive warehouse as persistency layer, which is, ultimately, still files, but with some extra organization. Using Hadoop in SAP ecosystem, I could utilize SAP Data Services with Hive adapter to load files from outside into Hadoop (and dump data from Hadoop into files, if required), and make that data available via Vora.

Comment: SAP Vora is built on top of Spark so anything that can be done with Spark can be done with Vora. As far as I know Vora isn't physically storing any data, it just creates in memory tables. So if you are looking to store your data in Hadoop then I would just keep them in Hive tables, but if you are looking to use Vora as an extract tool out of Hadoop then that is something completely different. What are you looking to do?

Comment: @TheRandomSuit I understand that neither Vora nor Spark offer data persistence. That's precisely why I'd like to use Hive warehouse as persistency layer (which is, ultimately, still files, but with some extra organization). That way I could utilize e.g. SAP Data Services with Hive adapter to load files from outside into Hadoop (and dump data from Hadoop into files, if required). Makes sense?

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. You should update your question with this additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to load/migrate Hive tables into Vora. Creating Vora tables based on (Hive-organized) files in HDFS would be the way to go.

The `paths` option allows to use a wildcard `*` to load all files from a particular directory in HDFS. This works for csv, parquet, orc. E.g. `paths "/path_to_my_dir1/*,/path_to_my_dir2/*"`

Comment: looks like I had hive.exec.stagingdir incorrectly set (by default) and staging directory appeared right inside table's directory in Hive, hence ruining the Vora's wildcard processing